# Как удалить первую строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст

Есть string

```
("Hello world \n
Hello with new string \n
Hello again")
```

Как мне удалить только первую из строк? Т.е. должно получится

```
"Hello with new string \n Hello again"
```

Пробую такой вариант, но почему-то не работает

```
text.split('\n')[1:]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Пробую такой вариант, но почему-то не работает

Это потому что, `split`, `срезы` и прочие методы строки ее не изменят в любом случае – строки в питоне неизменяемый объект. Поэтому, нужно после их применения получить результат и с ним работать.

---

- А вы так попробуйте:

  ```
  text = "Hello world \n Hello with new string \n Hello again"
  text = text.split('\n')[1:]
  print(text)  # [' Hello with new string ', ' Hello again']

  # Обратное объединение в строку
  text = '\n'.join(text)
  print(repr(text))  # ' Hello with new string \n Hello again'

  # Удаление лишних "пустых" символов: '\n', ' ', '\t', и т.п.
  text = text.strip()
  print(repr(text))  # 'Hello with new string \n Hello again'
  ```
- Вариант выше, но в одну строку:

  ```
  text = ' \n '.join(text.split(' \n ')[1:])
  print(repr(text))  # 'Hello with new string \n Hello again'
  ```
- Используя [str.partition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

  ```
  text = text.partition("\n")[2]
  print(repr(text))  # ' Hello with new string \n Hello again'
  ```
- Или так:

  ```
  # Находим индекс подстроки
  i = text.find('\n ')
  text = text[i+2:]

  print(repr(text))  # 'Hello with new string \n Hello again'
  ```
- Или регуляркой:

  ```
  import re
  text = re.search('.+?\n (.+)', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
  text = text.group(1)

  print(repr(text))  # 'Hello with new string \n Hello again'
  ```

---

**PS.** `repr` нужен был для отображения `\n` в результате

Comment: Еще вариант в коллекцию: `text = text.partition("\n")[2]`

Comment: @insolor, спасибо! :)